# How to import files from current directory in go

Tags: go, import, path

## Intro

I'm trying to import my `EventController.go` to my `main.go` file.

### Directory:

```
├───Controllers
│    └───Event
│        └───EventController.go
├───Models
├───Routes
│
└ Main.go
```

### Problem:

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    _ "/Controllers/Event/EventController.go" //problem here
)
```

error : `cannot import absolute path`

I read some documentation but the thing is I see that I'm doing it correctly, though i learnt about $GOPATH but I want to use the local directory thing.

What am I doing wrong and what's this error about

#### NOTE: I want add that I'm using windows as os

Thank you.

Comment: See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for a tutorial on how to structure and import Go code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- Packages are imported, not files (as noted in other answers)
- File absolute import paths are not valid as the error states. An application can use file relative import paths (the path starts with "./") or a path relative to the Go workspace.  See the [go command doc](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_syntax) for info on the syntax. Import paths relative to the Go workspace are the preferred form.
- It is idiomatic to use lowercase names for packages (and their corresponding directories). The camel case names in the question are workable, but it's better to go with the flow.

The document [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) is a nice tutorial on how to do this.

Here's how to reorganize the code given the above. This assumes that main.go is in a package with import path "myapp".  Change this import path to whatever you want.

```
-- main.go --

package main

import (
    "log"
    _ "myapp/controllers/event"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("hello from main")
}

-- go.mod --

module myapp

-- controllers/event/eventController.go --

package event

import "log"

func init() {
    log.Println("hello from controllers/event")
}
```

[Run this example on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BpZ6aLdH3KJ).

Comment: Thank you man for giving time to answer me, just to add on this that it's good to know how to create a module in your project so you can have your own project directory.
https://medium.com/mindorks/create-projects-independent-of-gopath-using-go-modules-802260cdfb51.
This link can help anyone to build a module.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import a file. You can import a package. So, lets say your main is the package "github.com/mypackage", then you should import "github.com/mypackage/Controllers/Event".

Answer (score -1):

Go supports package level import. You can import a package by adding it to the import statement at the beginning of the file.

In your case, you should do something like this-

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "Controllers/Event/EventController"
)
```

Also, you should remove first "/" from the file name

`_ /Controllers/Event/EventController.go" //problem here`

because your *Controllers* folder is at the same level as *Main.go* file. You should always give relative path in the import statements.

In this way, you can use any file which is listed under *EventController* folder.